# change centre of map in ggplot2 maps (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, coordinates

I want to draw a map that is centered on a specific longitude. This is what I've tried:

```
require(maps)
require(ggplot2)
require(mapproj)

t <- map_data("world2")

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = t, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group),fill ='gray',color=NA) +  
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")
```

Gives map centred at 200 longitude. I want to change it to 180, so that West Africa won't appear on the other opposite of the map. Adding `xlim` does not seem to work:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = t, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group),fill ='gray',color=NA) +  
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-20,200))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this:

```
t <- map_data("world2",wrap=c(-25,335), ylim=c(-35,65))
```

Comment: Interesting but how do you apply this to any simple feature?